# Javascript document.getElementById not printing to element - strange issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

This context of this issue is it is a set of measurements needed for review by the user. I'm reviewing some of my code and changing it to bootstrap's classes. I have a php function - reviewSlide(); that prints out the necessary html. From there it calls javascript script - reviewGetMeasurement(); function to grab the measurements the user inputs.

The event that triggers the javascript function is -

```
<button onclick="slideforms_step17(event);reviewGetMeasurement();" class="mdk_slidesforms_btn"><?= (!empty($button_text)) ? $button_text : 'Next' ?></button>
```

The function runs then moves into the below function reviewSlide() however if I do have the following code everything runs perfectly and the measurements are gathered and printed to the page.

```
function reviewSlide() {
    <table>
        <tr width="33%">
            <table class="pktsq_measurement_table_my_account_table">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="pktsq_measurement_table_my_account_td pktsq_measurement_table_my_account_td_title">
                        Personal
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="pktsq_measurement_table_my_account_td">
                    Height
                </td>
                <td class="pktsq_measurement_table_my_account_td pktsq_measurement_table_my_account_td_measurement" id="userHeight"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </table>
...
}
```

If I remove the above table nothing works.

I have tried

```
function reviewSlide() {  
    <p id="userHeight"></p>
    <p id="userWeight"></p>
    ...
}
```

at the top of my function (which is at this stage above the table) and nothing comes up.

I've looked at other people's issues, some of the main problems were the page wasn't loading and you would have to wait for the page to load as the javascript would not see any html. But I believe I have a bit of a quirky problem here regarding the table code

Any help would be grateful. Thank you.

**UPDATE and CLARIFICATION (same as comments):**

I didn't write this so bear with me but yes reviewSlide is in php. To clarify I have a function stepxx() in a shortcodes.php file. Each step represents a slide and reviewSlide() also represents another slide, in this case the review slide with all the measurements. All this is written in html/php. In stepxx() there is a button tag that calls a javascript function slideforms_stepxx(event);. When each step is complete 1-xx, slidesforms_stepxx(event) is called to check the input.

This is where we come to the review slide. On the slide before the review slide we go into slideforms_step17 check the input and submit the values to the server via jquery. Then we enter the reviewGetMeasurement() function as seen above by `<button onclick="slideforms_step17();reviewGetMeasurement();....>`. ReviewGetmeasurement's task is to print out the values and this is where my problem lies.

Inside reviewGetMeasurements(), if I print out the value for a variable let's say the height via console.log(height), it'll work and I can see the value in the console. But once if I try to print the value our by doing

```
document.getElementById("userHeight").innerHTML = height + "cm";
```

I get null. But I know there is a value height and it's not null. HOWEVER if I put the `<table>` code from above it will work and the values are printed out. If I use the `<p>` tags with the right id it won't work.

Comment: So... the `reviewSlide()` function is in PHP, right?  What do you mean "moves into the function below"? Can we assume that the `reviewGetMeasurement()` function (which is in Javascript) relies upon the classes (and ID) that are outputted in your PHP function `reviewSlide()`?  If they are, then add the classes into your new `reviewSlide()` function to see if that works.

Comment: I didn't write this so bear with me but yes reviewSlide is in php. To clarify I have a function stepxx() in a shortcodes.php file. Each step represents a slide and reviewSlide() also represents another slide, in this case the review slide with all the measurements. All this is written in html/php. In stepxx() there is a button tag that calls a javascript function slideforms_stepxx(event);. When each step is complete 1-xx, slidesforms_stepxx(event) is called to check the input.

Comment: This is where we come to the review slide. On the slide before the review slide we go into slideforms_step17 check the input and submit the values to the server via jquery. Then we enter the reviewGetMeasurement() function as seen above by <button onclick="slideforms_step17();reviewGetMeasurement();....>. ReviewGetmeasurement's task is to print out the values and this is where my problem lies

Answer (score 2):

You can't just blindly put HTML inside of a Javascript or PHP function.  What's in those functions must be the appropriate type of code, not HTML.

If it's Javascript, then using Javascript you can create DOM elements and then insert them into the page.

If it's PHP running at page render time on the server, then you can use PHP's echo to insert content into the page.

If it's PHP running in an Ajax call, then you can also use echo to construct a response to the Ajax call.

---

Here's an example of inserting content into the page from a user event using a Javascript function:

```js
function insertContent(html) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {
    insertContent(document.getElementById("newContent").value);
});
```

```html
<input id="newContent" value="Some Text"> <button id="run">Insert</button>
```

Comment: Hi jfriend00. I understand your frustration but bear with me as I've only just modified what was given to me.

however I haven't mixed javascript and php/html together. Though I have mixed php and html. My background isn't in web programming, but echo'ing out lines of html code seems a lot more cumbersome than writing pure html and breaking it up with <?php some cool php code ?>

Comment: @bigubosu - I honestly can't tell what in your question is PHP and what is Javascript.  It appears that you have HTML embedded directly in `reviewSlide()` which is illegal whether it's PHP or Javascript.  Please show your whole PHP file so we can see what is really going on here.